# current_principal_is_member_of gives syntax error

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to use the following

```
datatable (Brand:string, Country:string, Store:string)
[
'brand1', 'SE', 'Store1',
'brand2', 'SE', 'Store2'
]
| distinct Brand, Country, Store
| order by Brand, Country, Store
| extend _groupToCheck = strcat(Brand, "-",tolower(Country), "-store-", tolower(Store))
| extend _isValidStore = current_principal_is_member_of(_groupToCheck)
```

But I am getting a syntax error on the _isValidStore = ....

The error os as follows:

```
current_principal_is_member_of: argument #1 must be a constant string or constant dynamic array of string literals with up to 64 elements
```

I tried using mv_expand etc  but I cannot seem to get it in the correct format

How can I format the _groupToCheck value so its accepted by the current_principal_is_member_of?

I wanted the final result to be

```
Brand, Country, Store, isValidStore
Brand1 SE Store1 1
Brand2 SE Store2 0
```

Depending on the result for the ad call

Comment: Matt, I got a strong sense of [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Could you please share the full context of what you're trying to do and not just technical pieces of it?

Comment: This is what I am trying to do, from that datatable I only want to show stores the user has access from as defined from the result of the ad call, I found a way to build the string with the exact group name based on the data in the table, then I want to check for each row using that concatenated string if that equals an ad group and if so it means I can show that store in the data explorer dashboard parameters view if the isValidStore is 1 ( or 0 or whatever the expressions is as long as I can filter it)

Comment: the final result is to use this for dashboard parameters so that the parameter query in the dashboard would be all stores with isValidStore == 1

Comment: Well, the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/current-principal-ismemberoffunction?pivots=azuredataexplorer) say 'constant string literal' or a list of such so I would assume that you simply cannot do this as it stands currently. I pressume that this restriction exists due to performance reasons: Imagine you let this loose on a few million rows (or even just thousands) - ADX would have to hit AAD for every single one which would have the potential to either DOS your AAD service or make the query timeout in any but the most trivial cases.

Comment: The function seems to accept any string, but it will only work with roles/ids. 
Example:
//the first one will return true or false, the second one will return an exception.
let x = 'aadgroup=RA999-S-BETA_ABCD_MYREADER_READONLY;4711-xx1-xx2-815b-bf0f94754e033';
let y = 'somedummystring, really';
print (current_principal_is_member_of(y));